# Camera Calibration Using 3D Points And 2D Points

Tags: camera-calibration

I need some Help. I have written the Code for Camera Calibration Which is giving me the Camera Matrix , Rotational Matrix and translation Matrix. But in case of Camera Matrix I am getting the Image Centers which are the out the range of the Image Size Can anyone Tell me why it is coming out the image size.

My Second Point is as I am finding Projection Matrix from different positions of the same structure but Still the Focal Lengths are coming different for the same camera. Can any One tell my why it is coming like this.